# How to check if it is an empty content while generating Jasper Report?

Tags: jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I generate a PDF report in Jasper using `exporter.exportReport()`.

Finally I get a blank page. Is there any way to handle or check whether the report content is empty so that I'll write my logic accordingly.

Edit:
The report generation is done in Service. So finally I get a byte array in my local class. Is it possible to do the validation with the returned byte array?

Comment: I have purposed a duplicate, see the answer on that, if you still have doubts pass a comment.

Comment: If no doubts consider to accept the duplicate : )

Comment: Question has been edited Petter Friberg

Comment: Check the duplicate, control the JasperPrint, before you export it and return for example null from service?

Comment: Thanks, Petter Friberg. Since it is a Service class, it might be used in several places in the project. So the returned null will affect all the caller methods.

Comment: Well all the caller need to know if it is a empty or not?

Comment: Check the lenght of the byte array, probably its always the same length when empty. However I would return null or similar from service so that everyone who uses it know it is empty without checking.

Comment: May be. But not compulsorily it needs to know to it is a empty or not.

Comment: No it returns different length for different empty reports.